# Get a selected value from a slate code sandbox

Tags: palantir-foundry

I'm trying to make a dropdown list with the code sandbox in the palantir slate, but I can't capture the selected value of the button in a function like the existing dropdown button, is there any way to capture this value with the code sandbox?

[This is my code sandbox button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuqMl.png)

[I am trying to capture the selected button value from this function tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJuDF.png)

I am new to stack overflow, if you need more information just let me know, I am grateful to everyone who has offered to help me.

I tried to capture the value with selectedValues but apparently this option does not exist. I also tried with javascript for "document.getElementById("standard-select");"
but the console always returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get a value from the Code Sandbox to the Slate context.
You can follow this : https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/widgets-advanced/#setstate

In short, You need to use the state of the Code Sandbox widget :

- In the "Interaction" tab of the Code Sandbox, you need to specify an arbitrary state's variable, for instance : `{"dropdownValue": "default_value"}`
- In your custom JS in Code Sandbox, you will store the value of interest (the value of your dropdown, for instance whenever it changes) in the state of the Code sandbox `SlateFunctions.setState("dropdownValue", 4)`
- In your Slate's function, you can access the Code Sandbox state as any other variable : `return {{w_mycodesandbox.state.dropdownValue}}`

Whenever you call `setState` from your custom JS, you update the state, hence the variable the Slate function depends on, and dependencies will run as expected.

Answer (score 3):

We can get a selected value from a Slate code sandbox by using the getSelectedValue() method. This method returns an object containing the currently selected value from the Slate code sandbox. The object contains the value, type, and range for the selection.